# Android: Navigation Drawer Top and Bottom ActionBars

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

The app I am working on has the bottom `ActionBar` for the `MainActivity` set in `Menifest` as

```
<meta-data
  android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
  android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

As I am using Navigation Drawer and I want to add some Items to the Top ActionBar of one of the Fragment on Navigation. But when I add an item it always show up in the bottom ActionBar. I need some help how can I achieve this, as I am using Fragment not activity and I cannot add this in Menifest for the Fragment.

Comment: how're you adding menu options, in fragment

Comment: @NitinMisra I am adding Items from menu/xml file

Comment: are you adding `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your `fragment`

Comment: Yes i am adding this

Comment: you can try sherlock action bar for this it will solve your problem